# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - nikto web server scanner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this problem though, I downloaded nikto from **cirt.net/Nikto2** and I have put it in **D:\Python27\soricy\nikto\**.
When I do:

```
D:\Python27\soricy\nikto>python nikto.pl
```

I expect program to output HELP contents but instead
outputs this:

```
  File "nikto.pl", line 2
    use strict;
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image]
I haven't touched the file or anything. I am running Windows 7 Service Pack 1 - 64 Bit
Any reason why this doesn't work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PL file is a script written in Perl that is compiled and run using a Perl interpreter.

It seems that you try to use python in order to run the program, you should use perl to run it.

Comment: Oh god, you're right. I'm was so confused and blind lol.
Thank you so much sir!